# Android testing sms from emulator

Tags: android, sms

If the application using sms-sending and receiving how is it possible to test it within the emulator?

Comment: hi, i think that is not posible in emulator. coz there is no IMEI number and all other information so. but not sure.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is so simple first start the emulator and launch your application.
now if you have another project(any) launch this in another emulator.
On the other emulator start sms application and send sms to the emulator in which your app is running.The phone no. is simply the emulator number like 5556 or 5554.

### Edit

Now You can send an SMS or make a call using `Emulator Control`. In Eclipse go to `window->show views->other->Emulator control`.

Comment: That is for sending/receiving SMS between built-in messaging application of the Android OS. If an emulator A expects to receive the SMS through its 3rd-party application from an emulator B, then we should specify the sender's phone number something like this "1555521555X" (X=4,6,..) in the application of the emulator A.

Answer (score 10):

Now we can use [emulator's extended control](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#extended) to send directly to the emulator.

1. Open Extended controls window.
2. Open Phone tab
3. Enter message and send

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Check this for Sending SMS to the Emulator using Port.

[Sending SMS for Emulators](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android)...

Answer (score 2):

You might want to refer to one of my article on handling Emulator SMS: http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/sending-messages-among-devices/