# How to enable messaging service in Visual Studio Emulator to test SMS related features of Android Apps?

Tags: android, android-emulator, messaging, visual-studio-emulator

I need to test a feature of the app which requires SMS (messaging) feature.

I searched and found ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638252/android-testing-sms-from-emulator)) that one can do so by setting the recipient's number to the Emulator number. But my requirement is a bit different now. How to do the same in VS Emulator?

The issues I'm encountering are:

- The emulator number is not just a number in this. It seems like it's an IP address with the port number. I don't have any idea to input an IP with the port in Phone number (which, in my app, is not allowing to enter more than a single dot, let alone the colon required to separate the port).

[image: No simple emulator number]

- It should have been the first issue though - Messaging is not enabled in VS Emulator. I couldn't find any documentation (or workaround) to enable it either.

Yes, I can test it using the default Android Studio Emulators but they are painfully slow and will also need to disable hyper-V and then rebooting. So it'd be great if there's any way to accomplish the same in VS Emulator only.

Moreover in the [article at MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studios-emulator-for-android/), they've not said anything about messaging in the 'Limitation' section, so maybe there is some way to get it done.

Thanks

Comment: did you find a solution to this..I am having the same issue..Can't find the sms app

Comment: @krv No, I couldn't.
I'll suggest you to use Android Studio emulator only (if you are not developing the app in Xamarin, to which I really have no answer; try posting on Xamarin forums maybe). The reason I switched to VS emulator was the speed and the latest AS emulator is quite fast as well.